# Why does my relative positioned element collapse when I change the width and height to right and left?

Tags: html, css

I created just a basic HTML document with just the `div` in it to experiment with positioned elements. I noticed when I change the width and height to left and right, the element collapses. Why is that?

```css
.div {
  position: relative;
  background-color: blue;
  right: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be conflicting arguments, left and right saying to go either left or right... try only using on argument for vertical and 1 for horizontal.

I mean You expected nothing to change and nothing appeared...

Also put somethign in that div, like `<h1>something</h1>` at least

Comment: I saw on the you tube channel devtips that with an absolute value you can stretch elements with the left and right property, I tried it with the relative and it didn't work, i was curious as to why https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rf6zAP4YnZA